# Error in as.data.frame.default when fitting a GAM

Tags: r, regression, gam

I am using `gam` R package. When I use `step.Gam()` to perform a stepwise regression I get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gam)    

data(mtcars)

df = mtcars %>% mutate(vs = as.factor(vs),
                       am = as.factor(am))

f0 = as.formula("mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am + gear + carb")
m.gam.0 = gam(f0, data = df)
f.gam.step = gam.scope(frame = (df %>% 
                                  select(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
                                  as.data.frame()),
                       response = 1,
                       arg=c("df=4"))

m.gam.step = step.Gam(object = m.gam.0, scope = f.gam.step, direction="both")
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Try using a different variable other than `df` since `df` is a base R function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have changed the name of the variable from 'df' to something else, and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `df` is base R function, hence it is treating the variable `df` as a function rather than dataframe. If you change the dataframe name to something else which is not a function name instead of `df` it should work.